# Use edge detection to segment images

Tags: python, contour, image-segmentation, opencv

I have an RGB from which I detected the edges and I'm curious if I can use it to optimize a segmentation or as a mask to improve the segmentation to identify cultivated fields.

Could you do that? If yes, how?

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('path_to_RGB.tif')

canny = cv2.Canny(image, 100, 200, 1)

cnts = cv2.findContours(canny, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image,[c], 0, (36,255,12), 2)

cv2.imwrite('C:\\canny.tif', canny)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]